# How to improve LIKE query speed with LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm having trouble with queries taking too long (over 7s).

There are 4 tables involved when I need to conduct a search:

- Videos
- Categories
- Tags
- Video Tags

If for example the query is "example string", then the SQL would be as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.id v_id, ca.id ca_id, ca.title ca_title, v.title v_title
FROM videos v
JOIN categories ca ON ca.id = v.category_id
LEFT JOIN video_tags vt ON vt.video_id = v.id
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id = vt.tag_id
WHERE v.title LIKE "%example%" OR v.title LIKE "%string%" OR
    ca.title LIKE "%example%" OR ca.title LIKE "%string%" OR
    t.name LIKE "%example%" OR t.name LIKE "%string%";
```

The problem is with the LEFT JOIN. I tested the speed of the query without it, and it comes back in less than 1s, but with the LEFT JOIN, the query takes over 7s.

How can I optimize this query so that it can be quicker. The tags table has over 7,000 rows and continuously growing. It also has a UNIQUE index on t.name.

EDIT 1 - Simplified schema:

**Videos:**

- id: varchar(15) [PK]
- category_id: int [FK]
- title: varbinary(127) [INDEX]
- duration: int
- description: BLOB

**Categories:**

- id: int [PK]
- title: varchar(31) [INDEX]

**Tags:**

- id: int [PK]
- name: varchar(255) [UNIQUE]

**Video Tags:**

- tag_id: int [PK]
- video_id: varchar(15) [PK]

Comment: We'd need to know what your tables are like. Did you try an `EXPLAIN SELECT`? Did you read the chapters in the manual about optimising your queries?

Comment: Create index in all columns that will be matchers like vt.video_id, v.id, t.id, vt.tag_id, v.category_id and ca.id

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I added a simplified version of my schema.

Comment: @Roy All the ID columns are either primary keys or foreign keys, aren't those columns automatically indexed by MySQL?

Comment: Try it, i think PK is not like INDEX

Comment: `%example%` type queries cannot be indexed, thus are doomed to be slow. If you have some kind of search engine, you may want to try full-text search.

Comment: Ok, now did you follow my other advice?